# does eclipse support the abstract enum in java7 ,how to enable it?

Tags: eclipse, enums, abstract, java-7

How can i enable "abstract enum [SomeClassName]" in eclipse with jdk7 ?

With Indigo Service Release 2 and jdk7, it will report error in the code when I write "abstract enum [SomeClassName] ".

Is there something I need to do in order to get this working ?

i need that feature very much, which reduce my labor dramatically.

Comment: no,no,no ,i believe it is  ---- abstract enum [SomeClassName]

Comment: not ----   abstract Enum , its legal, and i know that.

Comment: no way to edit my original post.

Comment: Where did you read that Java 7 supports "abstract" (or "extended") enums? They were considered, but not adopted in the end, so Java does not support them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, I agree with Philipp. Java 7 does not seem to support abstract enum. This is not a problem in eclipse.

The code that you think is problematic, can you get it to compile from command line using JDK 7 ?

I tried both OpenJDK-7 and the Oracle JDK7. I could not get a simple class to compile with an `abstract enum` in it.

Comment: I have a theory... abstract enum or method parameter names will collapse java2ee. so... they reluctantly to add those feature.